# Monitor stand that supports 3 monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor-stand

I currently have 3 [Asus VH236H](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824236059) monitors. They are spread across my desk and can be hard to work with. I am looking for a stand or mount to bring my monitors closer together. My monitors have the VESA wall mounts.

**Requirements**:

- Must support my three 23 inch, 10 pound monitors
- Supports independent rotation, tilt, and pivot adjustments
- Height adjustable
- Stable
- NOT wall mounted. This should use the desk for support
- Less than $250 USD

My desk is not up against the wall and is about 1 1/8 inch thick. It is made of solid wood, so screwing into it (preferably from the bottom) is not a problem. All that I ask is that I do not have to damage the walls.

Comment: That's 30 pounds total for anyone who's too lazy to do the math ;)

Comment: Are you able to clamp the mount to the back of the desk? I.e. does it have a "lip" you can access, or is it snug up against a wall and immovable?

Comment: Relevant meta post if people want to discuss the scope of the site: http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/50/1. This question is on an edge that I'm not sure we've fully hashed out yet. Good question, IMO, though :)

Comment: @Undo The desk is not against the wall. I do have access to clamp it to the desk from behind. The desk is approxamatly 1 1/8 inch thick.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about accessories and thus, out of scope here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about [electronic hardware](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/50/57). I don't think this falls within the scope meta discussions have led toward.

Comment: I'd argue for this question to be included in our scope, I've posted my reasoning [here](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/172/74).

Comment: Such accessories are inextricably linked with electronics. Imho it is on topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[VIVO Triple LCD Monitor Desk Mount](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009S7ALH8) seems reasonable.

Pros:

- **VESA Mount (75 X 75 & 100 X 100 mounting holes)**
- Tilt: -15 to +15 Degree - Swivel: 360 Degree - Rotate: 360 Degree
- Heavy Duty & High Grade Steel and Aluminum
- Fits Three Screens up to 24
- Integrated cable management system
- Monitor can be installed either in portrait or landscape shape
- Fully adjustable arms
- Center Post is 18" tall and the mounting brackets are exactly 21" on center (apart)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here is the [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA3BG16H8959&cm_re=VIVO_Triple_LCD_Monitor_Desk_Mount_Stand_%28STAND-V003%29-_-9SIA3BG16H8959-_-Product) link in case anyone wants to look at more reviews

Answer (score 5):

I have been using the dual version of the [Allcam monitor bracket](http://www.allcam.biz/catalog/index.php?cPath=29&osCsid=b18d42ad17d6e778ddf48a8714dea5dd) for a few years now, and I love it - no problems with 2 x 24" flat screens.  The height is a little tricky to adjust but the mobility is good horizontally and tilt is available without an issue.  It supports 3 screens and beyond (it is modular).

It is a desk mounted bracket and it supports weights in excess of 13lbs, so it seems to fit your requirements.

The invoice I dug up tells me that in 2011 I ordered the following from Allcam directly:

- 2 x Long Arm for Allcam MDM0X series LCD Monitor Desk Mount Bracket
- 1 x MDM05 Multi Screen Desk Mount Bracket

That came to a total of just over €100 thanks to high taxes and delivery charges to Ireland, but still not excessive.

You would need 2 of the long arms, one short and MDM06 instead, but it's pretty modular, so it's really up to you.  Here's [a link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B001H2XEP8) to the Amazon (UK) version of the MDM06 with decent pictures and an idea of price - I would have used Amazon when I ordered but it was not an option.

I have moved twice since I ordered and had to disassemble and reassemble each time - it's a little tricky if space is tight or you have a tight fit with a wall (but you mention you don't) - but otherwise it is solid, and I have never had any concerns about stability.

While searching for a decent shot of the triple set up I spotted that Allcam have a guide up on Youtube showing you how to set up the triple monitor [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLMAjotw2Og) so you can get a decent idea of what's involved and how it might look.

As an aside: this was one of the best quality of life things I ever did - I highly recommend it if you can manage the fitting and your desk will hold up - it frees up an insane amount of space.

Comment: Can you rotate the middle monitor without taking the monitor off first? I would like to try a landscape, portrait, landscape orientation first (-|-), but I'm not sure if I would like that. Its not a huge deal if it isn't, I just want to know before getting it. It didn't seem that way from the video.

Comment: The middle one is the one I don't have to confirm in person.  I can tell you that on the longer arms you can indeed rotate to portrait without a problem (also makes cabling them up easier). In the video the joint used looks the same and it seems to be rotatable.  You will need to move the longer arms out of the way to rotate the middle one but then you can just move them back - you will also have to mount it high enough to allow for rotation into portrait - my preferred viewing height was sufficient to do this without modification.