# Monitor stand that supports 3 30'' monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor-stand

My question is just like [this one](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/402), except for bigger monitor size and smaller requirements. My monitors are 30'' HP LP3065 (old but huge) and the recommended VIVO Triple LCD Monitor Desk Mount works up to 24''.

My main requirement is stability. While I'd strongly prefer a desk mount, a wall mount might be an option.

I'm considering using all three monitors rotated, as otherwise, their total width would be needlessly big while I could use some more vertical pixels.

Comment: Since asking that question, I have since upgraded my setup that includes two 25" (in portrait) and a 28" (in landscape) setup. I think the monitors were heavier than 10lbs, and the stand still works great. That monitor stand might work for you if all three are rotated, and if they are not that heavy.

Comment: @maaartinus How much do they weigh?

Comment: @Jeff 30.6 lbs, but that's the total, including the stand. Currently, I can neither find nor measure the weight of the display alone.

Comment: @maaartinus I used this one https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00I3IMWNY/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and it worked for me with some modifications on 27" screens.  (3 Side By Side)  Let me get you some photos of the changes and a materials list you need to make it work.  Took me about 2 hours including installing all the monitors and it works GREAT.

Comment: Do you have a budget we can account for @maaartinus

Comment: @E.Nunn Not really, but given that the cost for the stand from the linked question was <$60, I'd expect to stay <$120 (depending on the features, I'd raise the limit).

Comment: The weight of a single monitor is approximately 13.4 kilos (29.5lbs) according to this datasheet http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/pscmisc/vac/us/product_pdfs/LP3065_data_sheet_May07.pdf

Comment: I literally can't find anything that will support that kind of weight with stability. 3 of the things is 90lbs ffs :p. One option is to have three separate heavy duty arms and place them in such a way that they will be perfectly aligned.

Comment: @EdwardNunn I can't find anything either, and every item that might be even remotely close is way outside of OP's price range. Even getting three separate articulating monitor stands would be $400 easily.

Comment: @jcam3 That's the problem, I have a quality arm myself as I have a heavy color accurate monitor for design work, but these clock in at 200 USD each